# Making side-effect free methods static

Tags: java, static

A few days ago I made a code review and I noticed that several `static` methods have been introduced. When I talked to the colleague who opened the pull request, he told me that he makes side-effect free ([not pure](http://www.braveclojure.com/functional-programming/#Pure_Functions__What_and_Why)) methods `static` as it would help to deal with side effects. He stated that this way you easily see which methods lead to side effects and which don't.

Personally, I disagree here. Despite the fact that there are many `static` methods which cause side effects (just have a look at [`System`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html)), `static` methods often (not always) lead to problems, for instance during testing.

However, `static` isn't bad per se and I know every day is a school day. Is this a pattern I'm missing? What is the advantage of making a side-effect free method `static`?

Comment: What kind of method are you talking about? Small private helpers or public stuff? IDEA even has an Inspection that tells you a private instance method should be static if it doesn't depend on `this`.

Comment: If a method does not access the state of the current instance, and is not an implementation of an interface method or an override of an abstract method, it should be static, side effects or not. Static methods are good for eliminating code duplication, because common code can be shared in a helper method. Pure functions (i.e. functions with no side effects) are excellent candidates, too. In fact, there is no reason to make pure functions non-static.

Comment: The term *pure function* may be useful here, and if a static function is a pure function, there's no issue with testing.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight You forgot to mention "isn't overridable".

Comment: @F.Klein Saw this question before but I think it's too broad.

Comment: I see no difference between pure and non-pure functions here. It's about the need to dereference `this` and being subject to dynamic dispatch.

Comment: @beatngu13 Your question is too broad, too, for the same reason that most "what are the pros and cons" questions are too broad.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight AFAIK pure also means referential transparent, not only no side effects ([see here](http://www.braveclojure.com/functional-programming/#Pure_Functions__What_and_Why)).

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Both, `public` and `private` stuff. Didn't know about that IDEA feature, great hint!

Comment: `public` and `private` have very different character, to the point of being two separate questions. Making `private` methods `static` is a no-brainer, but public methods are usually subject to dynamic dispatch. If they aren't (`final` methods) and they don't access `this`, then they don't belong to the class and should be moved to a static utility class.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Do you have a reference to the inspector rule you mentioned? Your comments have been a great help so far, why not writing an answer? :)

Comment: There's a Java -> Performance Issues -> Method may be 'static' inspection.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`static` methods are only indirectly related to the concern of side effects. In the case of a private method, it can be made `static` if it doesn't dereference `this`. One of *many* consequences is that such a method does not mutate the object's state, which precludes one narrow class of side effects. Do not forget that the method may also accept arguments and mutate them; and even without that it can always access and/or mutate global state accessible over some static variable.

The real decision criteria are these:

1. Does the method dereference `this`?
2. Is the method subject to dynamic dispatch on the type of `this`?

If the answer to both questions is "no", then the method can safely become `static`.

The complaint that "static methods create problems for testing" is related to 2. above. In testing we sometimes have to provide mock overrides of a method. In that case the answer to 2. is "yes" and the method fails the criteria.

A private method should always be static if it can. In the split-second it takes to notice the `static` marker you will have gained the following important knowledge: the method doesn't deal with the object's state and doesn't call any other instance methods.

If a public method satisfies the criteria to become `static`, then it quite likely doesn't even belong to the class it's in because it has no coupling to it. In most cases such a method is a candidate for relocation into a static utility class.

Finally, the concept of *pure* functions (as opposed to just side effect-free) does matter here: pure functions are the least likely to ever need mocking. They are usually simple and fast to execute and their outcome can be controlled simply by supplying the appropriate input. Compare these two methods:

- `System.currentTimeMillis()`—no side effects, but depends on global state and its output cannot be controlled. Often the fact that it's non-mockable means trouble in testing as the tests become non-repeatable.
- `Character.toUpperCase(char)`—a pure function, performs a simple translation. You'll never have to mock this one.